# Where are the implementation of java.sql.Connection interface?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using the Interface Connection from the package java.sql

Actually I though it a Class but when I tried to look at the source code I figured out that it is an Interface.

In the source of the Connection interface there are only single line for each method without any implementation!!

What makes this interface works as it?

Database to connect to: MySql

Connection source code page:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/sql/Connection.java.html

Comment: What type of database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @drumboog : I am trying to connect to MySql

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not the interface that "works" but one of its implementations, which is specific to your particular RDBMS vendor. In fact, it is typically the vendor who provides the implementation of the `Connection` interface.

When you call

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
,    connectionProps);
```

driver manager searches through registered JDBC drivers, finds the one for MySQL (it knows it's MySQL from the connection string), passes connection properties to the constructor of the class inside MySQL JDBC driver that implements `Connection`, and returns the resultant `Connection` instance back to you. For example, the driver may return an instance of a package-private class `MySqlConnection` that implements `Connection`, and your program would use it to interact with RDBMS without knowing any details about the class, other than the fact that it implements `Connection`.

Comment: The DriverManager does not know which is the MySQL driver, it will simply query each registered Driver and ask if that Driver will accept the URL (using `acceptsURL`), the first to return true on that query will be asked to create the connection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Right, that is how it "knows" it's MySQL driver. I skipped the details of the trial-and-error process by which driver manager arrives at the particular implementation of the driver as a complicated detail that is not essential to the OP's understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL driver (http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) contains the actual implementation.  The java.sql.Connection interface just defines the methods that the JDBC standard expects.  Each database driver must define how to actually connect.

Comment: But I am using Connection to create my Objects? How does the compiler knows that this is not the empty Interface but the implemented Driver?

Comment: How are you creating the connection?  DriverManager?  From the web (JNDI Resource)?  Instantiating it directly?  The DriverManager uses a url to determine which type of Connection object to create.  Using JNDI Resources in a web container, you have to configure the server to tell it the actual type that should be used.  If you're instantiating it directly, then you'd just say `Connection conn = new MySQLConnection()` (not sure if that class name is correct).  One of the first two options is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of classes that directly or indirectly implement the java.sql.Connection interface:

- oracle.jdbc. OracleConnection Wrapper
- com.mysql.jdbc. ConnectionImpl
- com.microsoft. sqlserver.jdbc. SQLServerConnection

By the package namespace you can tell from which jdbc driver they are from. 
But these and other implementing classes are not to be used directly. As pointed out by dasblinkenlight, you're supposed to program against the JDBC API, not the classes provided within each JDBC driver library. Using the API will allow you to switch RDBMS and not breaking your java data access code.

Interesting enough, these days less and less people use the JDBC API. Many people use a object-relational mapping framework that is built on top of JDBC, such as Hibernate.